# Custom CSS not showing up in Google Chrome v34.0.1847.131 or IE 9

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been using Twitter bootstrap for a long time now but have recently ran into a problem that hasn't plagued me before. I am building a site and whenever I create a custom css rule, it doesn't take effect in Google Chrome or IE9. It works fine in Firefox. I've never had this issue in the past. Besides targeting specific browsers with css, what other options do I have for making things cross browser compliant? The only thing I've run into in the past was maybe something didn't work quite right in IE or I had margin and padding that was displayed slightly off in firefox, but nothing like this.

here is an example of a custom css rule that works fine in Firefox:

```
<div class="fullscreen2 background">
<p class="centertext">Meet the Team</p>
</div>

 .centertext {
        font-size:48px;
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
  }
```

Comment: What does "doesn't take effect" mean? Which property is not working? Seems unlikely to be a browser issue since .it's a 'problem' in Chrome and IE

Comment: basically this class that I create doesn't add any of the attributes in chrome or IE. I remember even a couple of weeks ago when I built things in bootstrap that it at least worked in chrome and firefox without much issues.

Comment: Without seeing it 'not working' it's hard to comment. Do you have a live example..or a JSfiddle.net reduced case?

Comment: Blind guess would be (a)path issue; (b)your Chrome AdBlock plugin. Without seeing a live demo we can't say anything more useful, for sure.

Comment: [link](http://spidey81.no-ip.org:8081/nickjosh/about.html) if you look at this in chrome you see "meet the team" in the top left corner of the full width image. In firefox it follows the css.

Comment: Godinall, I just disabled adblock for the site, css changes didn't take effect. I have a link in the comment above.

Comment: What is the CSS for fullscreen2 background?

Comment: .background {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    /* custom background-position */
    background-position:50% 50%;
    /* ie8- graceful degradation */
    background-position:50% 50%9 !important;
    }

    .fullscreen2 {
     width:100%;
     min-height:50%;
 background-image:url(../images/aboutsplash.png);
 background-size:cover;
 margin-bottom:80px;
  
    }

Comment: What is the result you are expecting? I got exactly same result on my Firefox and Chrome, plus Safari.

Comment: I want the text to be floated or at least centered with the font-size I gave it. I've been tinkering and it looks ok in firefox but not in my chrome which is v.34  I read chrome did away with webkit a few releases ago.

Comment: @user1968657 got it fixed for you, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it's your lucky day that I have the time and mood to actually go through your whole css file!

Below is your problem: (Line 371~375 in custom.css)

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
}//You are missing this closing brace!
```

Comment: Thank you so much Godinall!!! Much appreciated, not sure how I could have missed that. Thanks a million!

Comment: @user1968657 you are quite welcome mate, pleasure to be helpful. If you work with a group of guys that all seem to have picky eagle eyes you will also gain this ability to notice to details lol. Good luck with your SEO business BTW.